# Android DialogFragment onResume can't access views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I'm probably doing this in the wrong place, but currently I have a DialogFragment that represents a dialog with a camera button (among other things) and I'm using the built-in camera app (calling via an Intent) that returns to the DialogFragment's onActivityResult().

This all works great, but my goal is to find an attachments LinearLayout in my dialog and essentially attach a copy of the captured image to it. e.g. you takes some pics and they appear in the dialog's "attachments" section.

The issue appears to be that when the DialogFragment's onActivityResult() is triggered, I'm unable to get the its view, it's null:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               try {
                  LinearLayout attachments = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.landmarkAttachmentView); // <- getView() is null
```

I threw in a debug log in a couple of suspect methods I thought might trigger when the camera returned, that had the DialogFragment's view available, but none of them logged:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating landmark dialog view");
    if(getView() == null) Log.d(TAG, "No view!");
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Show landmark dialog view");
            if(getView() == null) Log.d(TAG, "No view!");
    super.show(manager, tag);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Restored landmark dialog view");
            if(getView() == null) Log.d(TAG, "No view!");
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onResume() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Resume landmark dialog view");
            if(getView() == null) Log.d(TAG, "No view!");
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Start landmark dialog view");
            if(getView() == null) Log.d(TAG, "No view!");
    super.onStart();
}
```

Only onStart and onResume triggered but this.view was null. How can I get my DialogFragment's view after it's returned from another activity/fragment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override onCreateView(), create your view there and return it back. Then it will be available in other methods too.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your_view_layout>, container, false);
}
```

Here is more documentation and an example:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Yup that did it. I implemented onCreateDialog() instead of onCreateView() initially. Since it returns a dialog, the view isn't set. However I had to move all my view setup code from onCreateDialog to onCreateView, while leaving the dialog specific stuff in onCreateDialog (like title, and not much else really) Thanks for the quick answer!